# I need help converting characters in a string to numerical values in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, vector

For example if the string input was "hello" then the output vector would be [7,5,5,12,12,16] corresponding with where the letter appears alphabetically,

Comment: `h` is the 8th letter, and `o` is the 15th, and there are only 5 letters, so it seems like the answer should be `[8, 5, 12, 12, 15]`, correct?

Comment: Yeah I messed up the count but the concept is the same

Comment: OK, then the link to the duplicate question should work for you.  If you still have trouble, feel free to post a new question with the code you're working on!